# ViewPager Click On NextPage

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using DeptPageTransformer()

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
```

and I can click on item on nextPage in viewPager.

Since I can't disable preloading nextpage with viewpager that i use, How can i prevent clicking on item on nextPage?

Comment: you can probably override the onClickListener, and see if the position is not teh current position, may be donot perform any action ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `onClick` event inside the root view of your first page xml.